# Python Pandas Create USD_Converted column

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, deals

```
Currency     Deal_Amount
0   USD           18.40
1   USD           18.40
2   USD           5559.00
3   USD           14300.00
4   USD           1000.00
5   EUR           3072.00
6   USD           500.00
7   CAD           100000.00
8   USD           250.00
15  EUR           6000.00
```

and currency_rates

```
currency_code   year quarter    from_usd_rate   to_usd_rate
AED             2018    3           3.67285      0.27226813
ARS             2018    3            17.585      0.056866648
AUD             2018    3            1.27186     0.786250059
BRL             2018    3            3.1932      0.313165477
CAD             2018    3            1.2368      0.808538163
EUR             2018    3            0.852406    1.173149884
GBP             2018    3            0.747077    1.338550109
GHS             2018    3            4.4         0.227272727
```

I want to create a column in deals that converts deals where deals['Currency'] != USD, and apply the currency_rate['to_usd_rate'] to deals['Deal_Amount'] to get the USD converted amount.

So far i tried

```
def convert_amount(data):
  if data['Currency']==currency_rates['currency_code']:
  Converted_amount=data['Deal_Amount'] * currency_rates['to_usd_rate']
  return Converted_amount
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `merge` and `fillna` with 1 to use as new rate

```
A = df1.merge(df2, left_on='Currency', right_on='currency_code', how='left').fillna(1)
df1['converted'] = A['Deal_Amount']*A['to_usd_rate']
```

output

```
    index Currency  Deal_Amount     converted
0      0      USD         18.4     18.400000
1      1      USD         18.4     18.400000
2      2      USD       5559.0   5559.000000
3      3      USD      14300.0  14300.000000
4      4      USD       1000.0   1000.000000
5      5      EUR       3072.0   3603.916444
6      6      USD        500.0    500.000000
7      7      CAD     100000.0  80853.816300
8      8      USD        250.0    250.000000
9     15      EUR       6000.0   7038.899304
```